# Django REST Framework: Directly display on results list in GenericView

Tags: android, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm using `djangorestframework` to manage a REST API that connects an Android mobile app to my Django web application. I have a list of objects that I need to retrieve from the web app through the REST API, so far a generic `ListCreateAPIView` works fine.

However, what the REST API returns isn't exactly a list/array *per se*, but a JSON object containing metadata and the actual `results` list. Here's an example of the said output:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "foo":"bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is, my mobile app's REST client expects a JSON list/array, not the JSON object above. Is there a way to make my generic view remove the `count`, `next`, and `previous` metadata and just output the `results` list itself? I need an output like the following:

```
[
    {"foo":"bar"},
    {"foo":"something"},
    {"foo":"another"}
]
```

Oh, and I'm not sure if this would be helpful, but I use Retrofit as a REST client for my Android app, which is supposed to connect to my web app's REST API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This object that wraps the array is generated by the queryset paginator. If you disable pagination you will get the array. To disable pagination, set `paginate_by` to `None`:

```
class PaginatedListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = ExampleModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleModelSerializer
    paginate_by = None
```