# Unable to get data from database to Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I'm trying to get data from my backend, Python and the database is in SQLite to my frontend in Angular. I think I have the function correctly but when I try to open the page, it gets me this error message:
`ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed`
I'm quite new to angular so any assistance on what could be causing this issue would be helpful. Thanks

This is my users.component.html:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">ID</th>
    <th scope="col">Username</th>
    <th scope="col">Email</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let user of userList">
    <td>{{user.ID}}</td>
    <td>{{user.username}}</td>
    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my users.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {UserData} from "./users.model";
import {AppService} from "../app.service";

export interface UserData {
  ID: number;
  username: string;
  email: string;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedUser?: UserData;

  userList: UserData[] = [];

  constructor(private appService: AppService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.getUsers().subscribe(
      response=>{
        this.userList=response
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Edit: On rahals' request. This is the get method in postman, getting a json of users:

```
"results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "first_name": "huh",
            "email": "damn@damn.com",
            "username": "damn"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "first_name": "son",
            "email": "damnson@me.com",
            "username": "Administrator"
        },
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of the data coming in from the backend using a tool like PostMan

Comment: userList must be an iterable (e.g. an array), make sure that the endpoint USERS_URL emits an iterable.

Comment: @serrulien but USERS_URL, thats just for the url of the database, how do I make sure that that part emits an iterable.   Rahal, sure I'll edit that right now

Comment: Just return a collection of objects in your back-end instead of just 1 User object. You can't assign a non-iterable object to an array.

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 if you could elaborate a bit more please. How would I go about that?

Comment: That depends on what your back-end solution is (Spring, Node, ...). The return type of the controller function you are talking to should just be a collection (Array, List, Set, ....).

Answer (score 0):

You can get more information out of your observable, which could help you find out what is going wrong:

```js
this.appService.getUsers().subscribe(
  response => { this.userList=response },
  err => console.log('HTTP Error', err),         // <-- Error handling
  () => console.log('HTTP request completed.')   // <-- Finally block
)
```

You might want to make sure your back-end is returning a collection of users of some sort instead of just one user, it is not clear from your question if that is the case.

```json
{      // <---- Object
            "id": 4,
            "first_name": "John",
            "email": "john.doe@me.com",
            "username": "JohnD"
}
```

This looks like an object.

```json
[     // <---- Array of objects
    {
            "id": 4,
            "first_name": "John",
            "email": "john.doe@me.com",
            "username": "JohnD"
    }
]
```

This is what an array of objects looks like.

```json
"results": [     // <---- Object with a field results, containing an array of objects
    {
            "id": 4,
            "first_name": "John",
            "email": "john.doe@me.com",
            "username": "JohnD"
    }
]
```

Your array seems to be wrapped, like this.

Your getUsers() function doesn't return an observable of type UserData[ ], but of type { results: UserData[ ] }

Comment: So when I run the get action on my postman, it gets me a couple of jsons with data about the user. It should be an array of results and it returns different dicts (jsons with the data). Now I added that code that you wrote there. When I inspect the page, I get the same errors that I was getting before, with the object object and only arrays and iterables are allowed. Also on top of that I get Http request completed.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the console output, or copy-paste the exact output

Comment: Just added it at the end of my post. You can have a look there

Comment: Try this:  this.userList = response.results, your array seems to be wrapped in an object. XD Also, Rahal is asking for actual debug information from your console.

Comment: I'm assuming you want me to add .results to the response line. It gets me the error message that results does not exist in UserData[]

Comment: The problem is you are not actually getting back an array of userdata... try making your request return type 'any'. This is not the right solution, but I bet it'll work.

Comment: Did you write the backend yourself? Because if so, you might want to change it to return an array, like we said earlyer. If not,  your data that is returned is an object with a field 'results' that contains your UserData[ ]. So your UserData[ ] is wrapped by an object.

Comment: Yeah I did write the backend my self. I'm just not too sure where I should make that change to be honest lol

Comment: XD Add your controller to the question, I'll have a look tomorrow. Need sleep.

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting this as answer instead of leanght comments.

From your question I don't see any issue from the Angular Code. probably the issue is with the type of data coming from the backend.
You thin you are getting an array ob objects. But you do not getting that type of data , it's something different. That's why Angular can't identify the attributes of the object. Best way to do is

1. Open **developer tools** in the browser (press F12)
2. Go to the **Network** tab
3. Then refresh the web page
4. you will see the response data for each request and by clicking the
   particular request you will identify the issue.
5. You will see something similar to [image: this image]

6. Check the response you got, if it's not following the **JSON array type** then that's the issue, you will be ned to fix it from backend

Based on the **updated question** you should change the code as follows,

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.getUsers().subscribe(
      response=>{
        this.userList=response.results
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: I just checked that. Now there's a bunch of stuff like localhost, main.js, runtime.js, websocket, and users/. the content type of users it says application/json and the status code is 200 ok. Does that mean that it's fine as it is? Or should I be looking for something else?

Comment: Hi @SikeYouTh please refer to my updated asnwer

Comment: Just solved the issue, it was the paginator on the backend causing all of this. It was wrapping the list inside an object. Changed the paginator on my view. Referred to this question right here for the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170442/remove-count-next-previous-from-response-in-django-rest-framework .  Thanks for the help though, wouldn't have figured it out if you guys didn't point me in the right direction!

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer, give an upvote if you think my answer somehow helped you :). Good luck

Comment: Did that, but I don't have enough rep for it to show, apparently I need more than 15, the feedback was recorded though :]

Comment: I got it. Good luck for the future